# How to make wait mode of answer after message from bot?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I am faced with the fact that I do not know how to make it so that after the message of the bot there is a waiting mode for a response from the user. How to make it?

NuGet Packages:
Telegram.Bot 16.0.1
Newtonsoft.Json

```
case "Ask question❓":
    {
        await client.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId: msg.Chat.Id, $"Write your question, to pin it on the chat-forum «{msg.Chat.Title}»!\n❗Please note that your question must follow the rules of this chat-forum.", replyMarkup: new ReplyKeyboardRemove());
        await client.PinChatMessageAsync(chatId: msg.Chat.Id, messageId: msg.MessageId);
        await client.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId: msg.Chat.Id, $"New question from {msg.From.Username}!", replyToMessageId: msg.MessageId, replyMarkup: GetButtons());
        break;
    }
```

Comment: A simple way is to add a call to `await Task.Delay(1000);` before `SendTextMessageAsync`. The argument to `Delay` is milliseconds, so that example is a 1 second delay.

Comment: @JackA. thanks for your attempt to help me but it's not work. Bot don't pin question, it pin message "Ask question". Video with test of bot: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QFA0z_QJUwSGW4zY3KWwSxNkTI5-2_Qf/view?usp=sharing)